# UIColor-subclass crashes when casting from Any?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, uicolor

I know, subclassing `UIColor` isn't recommended. Apple says

> Most developers have no need to subclass UIColor

But I do. More on why can be found from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59739137/overriding-or-extending-uicolor-to-support-certain-protocols) I posted yesterday.
That particular issue was solved, but I met another problem.

Let's say I have this custom color class:

```
class MyColor:UIColor{
    convenience init(test:String){
        self.init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    }
}

//Then do this anywhere:
let myColor = MyColor(test: "test")
let temp:Any? = myColor
let c = temp as! MyColor
```

This crashes. It crashes because it can't cast `temp` to `MyColor`:

> Could not cast value of type 'UIDeviceRGBColor' (0x..) to 'MyColor' (0x..)

`myColor` is an instance of `MyColor`. This same instance is stored in a variable of type `Any?`, and then cast back to `MyColor`. But it can't.

Though, if I cast it to `UIColor` everything works. But I can't do that in my case (explained in the previous question).

**Why doesn't this work?**

Comment: Have you considered to define the convenience init in an `extension UIColor` instead of subclassing? – `UIColor` is a “class cluster” which makes subclassing very difficult.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, the problem is that I need to implement a protocol which requires me to implement another init `init(jsonValue value: Apollo.JSONValue) throws`, and when implementing that in an `extension` I get several errors. One of them being `'required' initializer must be declared directly in class 'UIColor' (not in an extension)`.

Comment: I am not familiar with Apollo and do not have an answer right now. But note that `print(type(of: myColor))` prints “UIDeviceRGBColor” and not “MyColor”. That is typical for class clusters, and explains why the cast fails.

Comment: @MartinR Apollo is irrelevant, the protocol could just contain init(value: String) throws. I've been looking into class clusters now, but can't find a way to do what I need. Do you know if there's a way to manipulate how something like this to get a MyColor? I assume all the subclasses in the cluster are private and that I can't subclass any subclass, or add a custom class into the cluster..

Comment: Once you have created your myColor and you are out of Apollo can't you simply cast back to UIColor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `UIColor` is implemented as a so-called *class cluster*. It's a kind of class factory, but the factory is working *implicitly* under the hood.
In your example, if you *mean* to create a `MyColor` instance, what happens internally is the following:

- `MyColor.init` calls the initializer of the super class
- The super class then delegates to a internal class factory and changes the concrete implementation from `MyColor` into something adequate to the parameters, in your case `UIDeviceRGBColor`.
- This means, `UIColor.init` does return a different instance than the one you intended to create. This is a subclass of `UIColor`, but not of `MyColor` any more.

In Objective C, you can trace this behaviour more easily:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor alloc];
NSLog(@"Address after alloc: %p - class: %@", color, [color class]);
color = [color initWithRed:1.0, green:1.0, blue:1.0, alpha:1.0];
NSLog(@"Address after init:  %p - class: %@", color, [color class]);
```

You should get a different address and class after the initalizer has been called.

Comment: `"..return a different instance than the one you intended to create"`. If this is true I kinda find it weird that the compiler tells me that `let c = MyColor()` is an instance of `MyColor` instead of a `UIColor`. Class Clusters should have a special handling or indication of some sort to prevent this.. Because the code I've written compiles perfectly without error or warning, it just crashes in runtime..

Comment: Totally agree; this is a legacy of the Objective C runtime. I'm not sure if you can do so in Swift, but you might use Objective C to extend the class cluster, see https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-03-12-subclassing-class-clusters.html

Answer (score 1):

> UIColor is a class cluster use associative references in a category to
>   add properties! All of the custom init methods on UIColor return a
>   UIColor* not an id so you can not easily subclass UIColor nor should
>   you try.

There are two recommendations that you can follow below:

1- Extensions

> ```
> extension UIColor {
>
> convenience init(test:String){
>     self.init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
>    }
> }
>
> let myColor = UIColor(test: "test")
> ```

2- Composition

> ```
> class MyColor {
>
> private(set) var color: UIColor
>
> init(test:String) {
>     color = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
> }
>
> }
>
> let myColor = MyColor(test: "test") 
> let temp:Any? = myColor 
> let c = temp as! MyColor
> ```

Comment: Sadly, I can't use extensions (as far as I can tell) due to certain protocols I need to implement (explained in comments above and in the linked previous question). And the "composition" is what I currently have. I just wanted to make it more sexy by not having to use `myObject.color.color`, but I guess that's not possible:/